# Integral of derivative notation/terminology

Tags: integration, derivatives

In a problem solution I am given that $$\int^\infty_0 \left(e^{{-M^T}t}\Lambda e^{-Mt}M + M^Te^{{-M^T}t}\Lambda e^{-Mt}\right)dt$$
$$= - \int^{\infty}_0 d \left( e^{{-M^T}t}\Lambda e^{-Mt} \right)$$
$$= \Lambda - \lim_{t\to \infty} e^{{-M^T}t}\Lambda e^{-Mt}$$
$$= \Lambda$$

Is it correct to say that we've gone from step 1 to step 2 due to implicit differentiation w.r.t. to $t$? Following that, it's clear that we go to step 3 because what is shown is analogous to $$\int^b_a f'(t) = f(b)-f(a)$$

What puts doubt in my understanding of what is going on is the notation used, i.e. $d\left( e^{{-M^T}t}\Lambda e^{-Mt} \right)$ to represent $f'(t)$. Is this standard? It feels like something is missing, specifically that it should be $d/{dt}\left( e^{{-M^T}t}\Lambda e^{-Mt} \right)$. Is this correct?

Comment: There are many conventions used, some sloppier than others. I would prefer to define $f(t)$ as the integrand and then write it as you have with the $f'(t)$. One more line, a lot less ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $df=f'(x) dx$. It is a symbolic manipulation of the derivative written as a Leibniz quotient: 
$$
f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}.$$
There is nothing substantial here, just a mnemonic for the formulas of integration. Indeed, you can write the fundamental formula of integral calculus as follows: $$ \int_a^b df = f(b)-f(a), $$
which emphasizes the analogy with the discrete formula $$ \sum_{n=1}^N (a_{n+1}-a_n) = a_{N+1} - a_1.$$
But you don't *have* to use this notation. If you find it confusing, then just revert to the ones you are more comfortable with.